# Issue with Map<String, Entity> in JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have the following field in my entity

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
   name = "licensingpolicy_eulamatches"
)
Map<String, EULADocument> eulaMatches = new HashMap<String, EULADocument>();
```

I use JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink.

The table generated has a unique key constraint on the ID of the entity and the ID of the EULADocument (the value in the map) entity. This is wrong as I could certainly have several times the same EULADocument in my hashmap. I can modify the table definition but I would prefer if there was a more standard way of doing it.

(I could use an element collection but I would have to invert the key and value types and I'd rather not if possible)

Comment: So raise a bug on your JPA provider ... a unique constraint on id + value is dumb.

Comment: I just tried with two entities as well, and same issue, the constraints on the tables generated don't make any sense to me. I must be missing some annotation...

Comment: OK, so the behaviour seems to be that the unique key constraint is applied to the hashmap values instead of the key, this seems wrong to me, as the only thing that would make sense is to have a unique parent/key combination indeed.

Comment: Well... after some digging, it appears to be a known bug, since 2011, not fixed yet https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344448. I will vote for it, hopefully it will get some attention.

Comment: Simple workaround is to generate the SQL script and modify it. DDL generation is not something you would or should use for serious environments anyway.